# How to send our current location or last location of gps and network through sms in android application?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In this code I manually send the location what I want to send current location when user presses the button.

```
 {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Home.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},1);
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            StringBuffer smsBody = new StringBuffer();
            smsBody.append(Name + " Hi, I am in trouble Please help ! My Location Link http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
            smsBody.append("23.251295");//23.251295, 77.5245421//23.249159 //77.528058
            smsBody.append(",");
            smsBody.append("77.5245421");
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(Number, null, smsBody.toString(), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: There is any another way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use smartLocation library. It's very easy to use:
[SmartLocation](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib)